# How can mass spectrometry be used to determine concentration?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Which forms of mass spec will determine accurate concentrations of metal ions in a sample? Preferable not using GC/MS but can MALDI ToF or quadrupole do this somehow. Also, not relative concentration but actual concentration.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductively_coupled_plasma_mass_spectrometry), Inductively Coupled Plasma Mass Spectrometry (ICP-MS) is the technique of choice to quantify metal ions in a sample. In summary, this technique is based on the atomization and ionization of the sample metal atoms in a plasma torch, and the ions are then separated based on their mass, usually with a quadrupole mass filter, and then directly quantified on the detector. External calibration with standard solutions of known metal concentration or isotopic dilution then affords access to absolute concentrations.